# When using Cocotb, should I be using FallingEdge to set and assert values?

Tags: verilog, hdl, verification

I'm attempting to use [Cooctb](https://www.cocotb.org) to verify a simple Verilog counter with a reset:

```vhdl
`default_nettype none
`timescale 1ns / 1ps

module counter (
  input wire        clk,
  input wire        rst,
  output reg [7:0] count
);

always @(posedge clk) begin
  if (rst) begin
    count <= 0;
  end else begin
    count <= count + 1;
  end
end

endmodule
```

When I first wrote a test that verifies `count` goes back to `0` when `rst` is asserted, I used `RisingEdge` to set and assert values. However, I found that I had to wait for *two* rising edges for `count` to go back to `0`:

```py
    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 3

    dut.rst.value = 1
    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    # count == 4 here
    await RisingEdge(dut.clk) # Why is this needed?
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 0
```

Here's the signal trace for this `RisingEdge` test:

[image: RisingEdge trace]

Even though it *looks* like `rst` is `1` at the `6ns` rising edge, it must be getting set just after that edge, so it doesn't take effect until the `7ns` rising edge?

If I use `FallingEdge`, then `count` goes back to `0` on the next edge, as I expect:

```py
    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 3

    dut.rst.value = 1
    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 0
```

Here's the signal trace for the `FallingEdge` test:

[image: FallingEdge trace]

While this works, it seems a little odd to be using `FallingEdge` for all the test code, given the logic is synchronous to the rising edge. Is this how folks typically write Cocotb tests?

Here is the full Python code:

```py
import cocotb
from cocotb.clock import Clock
from cocotb.triggers import RisingEdge, FallingEdge

@cocotb.test()
async def count_then_reset_test_rising(dut):
    # Reset
    dut.rst.value = 0
    cocotb.start_soon(Clock(dut.clk, 1, units="ns").start())

    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    
    dut.rst.value = 1
    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)

    dut.rst.value = 0
    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)

    # Running
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 0

    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 1

    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 2

    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 3

    dut.rst.value = 1
    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    # count == 4 here
    await RisingEdge(dut.clk) # Why is this needed?
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 0

    dut.rst.value = 0
    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 0

    await RisingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 1

@cocotb.test()
async def count_then_reset_test_falling(dut):
    # Reset
    dut.rst.value = 0
    cocotb.start_soon(Clock(dut.clk, 1, units="ns").start())

    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    
    dut.rst.value = 1
    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    dut.rst.value = 0

    # Running
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 0

    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 1

    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 2

    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 3

    dut.rst.value = 1
    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 0

    dut.rst.value = 0
    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 1

    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 2

    await FallingEdge(dut.clk)
    assert dut.count.value.integer == 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Checking the value on the `FallingEdge` or the following `RisingEdge` feels unintuitive, but it does reflect how a real electrical system behaves. I wouldn't expect a stable value for the output of a physical DFF on the rising edge, and I wouldn't clock in any outputs until at least the falling edge.

Therefore, I would go with writing assert on the `FallingEdge` since it reflects real-world tests, and it's also more readable and clear than something like `ReadWrite`.

Answer (score 1):

I got an [answer](https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/discussions/3282#discussioncomment-5676420) on my [cocotb GitHub Discussions post](https://github.com/cocotb/cocotb/discussions/3282) from GitHub user [f-cozzocrea](https://github.com/f-cozzocrea):

> Checking the value on the `FallingEdge` or the following `RisingEdge` feels unintuitive, but it does reflect how a real electrical system behaves. I wouldn't expect a stable value for the output of a physical DFF on the rising edge, and I wouldn't clock in any outputs until at least the falling edge.
>
> Therefore, I would go with writing `assert` on the `FallingEdge` since it reflects real-world tests, and it's also more readable and clear than something like `ReadWrite`.

Comment: @f-cozzocrea posted their answer here, so marking that one is the "correct" one. Not sure if I should delete my answer, but keeping it here for now.